# Recycler and adapter does not work when called from OnSuccessListener (Firestore)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a recyclerView that loads fine when called directly from onCreate. However when inserting it into a Firestore Collection's onSuccessListener, it doesn't load. Here is a sample of the said code:

```
private void populateRecycler(String RootCollection, String UserID) {
    mQuery = mFirestore
            .collection(RootCollection)
            .whereEqualTo("UID", UserID)
            .orderBy("DateAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(mQuery, this) {
        @Override
        protected void onDataChanged() {
            if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                mOrdersRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mOrdersRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        protected void onError (FirebaseFirestoreSettings e) {
            // Show a snackbar on errors
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    // Populate and enable RecyclerView
    mOrdersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

But when I call `populateRecycler();` from another method that contains this code:

```
mFirestore.collection("UIDOrg")
            .document(UserID)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    UIDOrg uidOrg = documentSnapshot.toObject(UIDOrg.class);
                    mOrgTextView.setText(uidOrg.getOrg());
                    RootCollection = uidOrg.getRootCollection();
                    populateRecycler(RootCollection, UserID);

                }
```

...it does not work. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: To expound further, the code just stops before mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter. Seem like the new OrdersAdapter cannot load. When I insert a Log.d in there, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
  mQuery = mFirestore
        .collection(RootCollection)
        .whereEqualTo("UID", UserID)
        .orderBy("DateAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

in your `populateRecycler` method is async operation. That means that result will be available in the future. So you need to wait for the result before populating data.

Read this concept [chaining of the tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#chaining). And after your second task will be completed, then populate yours recycler view.

Comment: Why doesn't `populateRecycler` in the onSuccess work? Technically (correct me if I'm wrong), the data would have been available before `populateRecycler` is called because all the variable assignments would have been done by then.

Comment: data from your first query (mFirestore.collection("UIDOrg")
            .document(UserID)
            .get())
will be available in populate but not from second  (mFirestore
            .collection(RootCollection)
            .whereEqualTo("UID", UserID)
            .orderBy("DateAdded", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);)

Comment: you can just  add second on success listener to your second request

Comment: The 2nd mFirestore.collection(RootCollection) is only called after the first query's onSuccess though.

It is never called beforehand. 

I also have another Spinner populated via another call after that using a similar call but with a addOnSuccessListener, but that works fine.

Comment: How do I add a OnSuccessListener in my case? Can you point to some example? I'm using this to populate a RecyclerView, by calling OrdersAdapter class with mQuery.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CX2Wn

this is the error I get when I add an onSuccessListener.